# How to drag and sort the table column of Swiftui in a Mac program? Table is a native table

Tags: swiftui

How to use onDrag on a column title? I have three columns, userName,age and adress in swiftui table.How can I move my age to the first column?I searched for many documents and found no relevant operations.Can you help me?